# MySQL transaction issue with Django and Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, django, innodb, amazon-rds

I'm having a problem with a MySQL 5.5 database instance running on Amazon RDS. Periodically (once every couple of days) a transaction will fail to complete and appears to leave the tables locked. Normally the transaction times out and everything returns to normal but several times the transaction stays open and the database continues to chew up CPU time along with more and more memory until it eventually runs out. I believe that the problem may lie with the django-reversion conflicting with another app (possibly django-taggit or django-celery) which is causing this strange behaviour.

I'd like to know if anyone has any experience with this particular problem

EDIT: Here is the error that MySQL throws most often

OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues with RDS. The techs were never able to nail it down.. we just moved it off RDS and back on to ec2 and the issues went away.